# font awesome shows white squares when I add helmetJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, helmet.js

Originally I made an app that uses this code in the html and follows with classes that implement font awesome icons and worked well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I am now learning helmetJS for the first time and have implemented it into my server.js file. I can set the controlSecurityPolicy to false, but I want to keep that feature and feels like that is taking a shortcut. When I call on the CSP I successfully add in images and jQuery to directives so they are working fine. However, when I do it for fontawesome it takes the icon and turns it into a white square.

```
app.use(helmet({ dnsPrefetchControl: false, contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
        "img-src": ["'self'", "https://i.ibb.co/"], // images
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"],
        styleSrc: [ "'self'", "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"], // LINK THAT IS NOT WORKING.
      },
    },
  })
);
```

There's got to be a way to fix the white squares and make them icons again after using helmetJS, but the answer has been eluding me. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Browser developer console for your server CSP configuration like below.
[image: Server Response]

If the header **content-security-policy** header does not come with font-awesome. Then it means the current CSP is not taken effect. Clear cache in your browser and try again or try it in the new browser to check it comes correctly.

[image: CSP]

Comment: it came up in the console like so: Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';img-src 'self' https://i.ibb.co/;script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js;style-src 'self' https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css. I then cleared cache and even tried on firefox and no luck.

Comment: Then try this one.

Instead of "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" 
Try simply "use.fontawesome.com"

Comment: You crazy son of a great mother you did it. I put "use.fontawesome.com" as you suggested in styleSrc after "'self'" and now the icons are showing once again. Thank you!